# Set QComboBox model to none

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qabstractitemmodel

When constructing a `QComboBox()`, the model is initially "empty" (i.e. no model attached). After assigning a model with `QComboBox::setModel()`, a model is attached. Now, I need to reset the `QComboBox` model to the previous state: "empty" or "none".

I have a `QCheckBox` called `chbW1` alongside a QComboBox called `cbWaehrung1`. Before I check the `QCheckBox`, no model is attached and the `QComboBox` is empty. If the `QCheckBox` is checked, I set the `QComboBox`'s model to `wmodel`. This part works.

Now if I uncheck the `QCheckBox`, I want the `QComboBox` to return to the previous state (empty). But it only gets disabled (by code, see below), keeps its index and text. If I turn it back on again (check the `QCheckbox`), the old value (index and text) is still there.

This is Qt 5.6 - The "else" part doesn't seem to work:

```
void MainWindow::on_chbW1_toggled(bool checked)
{
    ui->cbWaehrung1->setEnabled(checked);
    if (checked) {
        // working
        ui->cbWaehrung1->setModel(this->wmodel);
        ui->cbWaehrung1->setModelColumn(1);
        ui->cbWaehrung1->setFocus();
    } else {
        // not working
        ui->cbWaehrung1->clear();
        ui->cbWaehrung1->clearEditText();
    }
}
```

I had also tried something like

```
ui->cbWaehrung1->setModel(QAbstractItemModel());
```

But this gives an error at compile time:

> ```
> invalid cast to abstract class type ‘QAbstractItemModel’
>          ui->cbWaehrung2->setModel(QAbstractItemModel());
>                                                       ^
> ```

Also:

```
ui->cbWaehrung1->setModel(0);
```

This produces an error at runtime:

> cannot set a 0 model

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an empty model, but remember that `setModel()` takes a pointer to a model, and that `QAbstractItemModel` is (unsurprisingly) abstract:

```
auto *emptyModel = new QStandardItemModel(ui->cbWaehrung2);
ui->cbWaehrung2->setModel(emptyModel);
```

We set the `QComboBox` as parent of the empty model; this means that it take ownership, and delete the model when `setModel()` is called to set a new model.

You may prefer to arrange for `emptyModel` to be reused or deleted if you don't want to create a new one each time the function is called.  The easiest way may be to have a static empty model, and just pass a pointer to that:

```
static QStandardItemModel emptyModel;
ui->cbWaehrung2->setModel(&emptyModel);
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I go for that second version. Would like to upvote but my "reputation" is too low. How bizarre ;-)

Comment: If the answer helps you, you can mark it as accepted (use the tick symbol by the voting arrows).  I'm surprised you can't upvote answers to your own questions, even if you can't yet vote on anything else.  At least you can comment on such answers.  You'll soon have enough reputation, so don't worry too much!